# in MVC 5 how to pass selected value to html action in jquery ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using JQuery ajax to load some data when user selects something from the list. How do i pass value of selected option in action parameters?

I tried by creating variable selectedValue but it says name "selectedValue" does not exists.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#students").change(function () {
            var selectedValue = $("#students").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Sample", new { table = "Students", id = selected })',
                type: "GET",
                success: function (result) {                    
                    $("#information").html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the correct variable ? It looks like you are reading the value to `selectedValue` but not using that. Try this

```
var selectedValue = $("#students").val();
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetData","Sample")?table=Students&id ='+selectedValue,
        type: "GET",
            success: function (result) {                    
                $("#information").html(result);
            }
      });
```

This should work assuming your `GetData` action method has 2 parameters named `table` and `id`

```
public ActionResult GetData(string table,string id)
{
  //to do : return something useful
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the code that will work for you depends on how you route is setup, but regardless of how you have it setup you will have to append that selected value on the client side.

Assuming this style of route:

```
/Sample/GetData?table=Students&id=3
```

This should work for you:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#students").change(function () {
            var selectedValue = $("#students").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Sample", new { table = "Students" })' + '&id=' + selectedValue,
                type: "GET",
                success: function (result) {                    
                    $("#information").html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    })
```